# Why does Unicode have multiple planes?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, character

At the moment, Unicode has 17 [planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))

1. But **why** are there 17? Why aren't they all just included in 1 plane?
2. Why are the 4th to 13th planes unoccupied? I expected they might be contiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks like initially there was only one plane. But as Unicode has gone from it's first creation to now being on Unicode 13.0.0 as of March 2020, [more planes](http://vad-ev.de/en/unicode-characters-part-6/) were added each time.
2. Looks like they don't go contiguously because the first ones are used for encoding all languages, and the final places only contain non-graphical characters. The "gap" is left for any new text that needs to be added to Unicode. [Quote](https://en.wikipedia-on-ipfs.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode).html):

   > It is not anticipated that all these planes will be used in the foreseeable future, given the total sizes of the known writing systems left to be encoded. The number of possible symbol characters that could arise outside of the context of writing systems is potentially huge. At the moment, these 11 planes out of 17 are unused.